# How to make the wheel scroll as soon as someone enters the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a website. Wheel of Fortune, how to make the wheel scroll as soon as someone enters the page. In the code below, the system is designed in such a way that the wheel begins to rotate when you press a button. But you need it to rotate as soon as someone crosses to the page.

```js
// Immediately invoked function expression
// to not pollute the global scope
(function () {
    const wheel = document.querySelector('.wheel');
    const startButton = document.querySelector('.button');
    let deg = 0;

    startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Disable button during spin
        startButton.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        // Calculate a new rotation between 5000 and 10 000
        deg = Math.floor(5000 + Math.random() * 5000);
        // Set the transition on the wheel
        wheel.style.transition = 'all 10s ease-out';
        // Rotate the wheel
        wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
        // Apply the blur
        wheel.classList.add('blur');
    });

    wheel.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
        // Remove blur
        wheel.classList.remove('blur');
        // Enable button when spin is over
        startButton.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
        // Need to set transition to none as we want to rotate instantly
        wheel.style.transition = 'none';
        // Calculate degree on a 360 degree basis to get the "natural" real rotation
        // Important because we want to start the next spin from that one
        // Use modulus to get the rest value from 360
        const actualDeg = deg % 360;
        // Set the real rotation instantly without animation
        wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${actualDeg}deg)`;
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Weiben - Wheel of fortune</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body background="backg2.jpg">
    <div id="app">
        <img class="marker" src="marker.png" />
        <img class="wheel" src="wheel.png" />
        <img class="button" src="button.png" />
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener and use the callback of that to fire your code

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event